# One-To-Many where One can reference already existing Many in EF5?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a table called Products that have a Collection of Categories, giving the models like this:

```
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

*Entity base provides some additional properties like Id*

When running the migrations, EF creates a ProductId FK in the Category SQL table, so it can't hold multiple products.

The desired functionality is to have **multiple Products referecing the same Category**, how can be this done with One-To-Many relationship?

Comment: Where is your `OnModelCreating` method?

Answer (score 0):

if you want one category has many product you should do :

```
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product > Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In this case, isn't possible to have the same product in two categories? I want categories being capable to have multiple products that already exists and are in another category.

Comment: No.If you want to have one product in multi categories and each category belongs to only one product, your own code is correct, if you want one category has multi product and each product belongs to only one category, my code is correct.but if you want both, you have to create another table, which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
public Product Product { get; set; }
```

property to Category

and add a method in Product for categories

```
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    
    public Product () 
    {
        Categories = new Collection<Category>();
    }
}

public class Category : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasRequired(n => n.Product)
            .WithMany(n=>n.Categories)
            .HasForeignKey(n => n.ProductId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

in OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) in the context definition

Then regenerate Database